# PHP datetime end of month minus one month

Tags: php, function, datetime, dayofmonth

Of a given datetime I need the very end of the previous month.

For example:

```
$date_given = '2019-07-14 16:33:05';
```

should become:

```
2019-06-30 23:23:59
```

I have some possible solutions to make it in several lines. But the requirement for my program/script is to have it in one line. So something like this:

```
$date_result = ...somefunction..(($date_given) -1 month) ...;
```

It really would be helpfull to have everything in that one line and not have prior lines with functions.

Thanks.

Comment: Why does it need to be one line? That's not a logical requirement/constraint.

Comment: - one month is equal to `2019-06-14`

Comment: Set day of month to 1 then subtract 1 day. Then set time to 23:59:59. I dont understand why one liner Is required... But you can actualy type sentences to the datetime constructor So maybe you can do new datetime('last day of previous month') or so....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is many solution to this, but if has to be one line i would go with this

```
echo date_create($date_given.' last day of last month')->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59');
```

Comment: Works fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

I actually don't know if there is a a way to dynamically get the last hour/minute/second of a day but I guess we can safely assume it always is "23:59:59" so you could do:

```
$lastDateOfMonth = date("Y-m-t 23:23:59", strtotime($date_given . '- 1 month'));
```